Calculate SUMPRODUCT with multiple column criteria and one row criteria (with empty columns in the data range)
      |   A   |B |C|   D  |E|    F   |   G  |   H  |   I  |J|    K    |     L    |    M     |   
------|-------|--|-|------|-|--------|------|------|------|-|---------|----------|----------|--
    1 |       |  | |ratio | | tested | 2023 | 2024 | 2025 | | RowCrit | ColCrit1 | ColCrit2 |
    2 |Brand A|P1| |  7%  | |   yes  |  500 |   70 |   60 | |   2024  |  Brand A |    P1    |         
    3 |Brand A|P2| |  8%  | |   yes  |  100 |   47 |  300 | |         |  Brand D |    P4    |            
    4 |Brand A|P2| | 10%  | |   yes  |  800 |   21 |  200 | |         |          |          |          
    5 |Brand B|P1| |  5%  | |   yes  |   90 |   56 |  150 | |         |          |          |                     
    6 |Brand C|P4| |  3%  | |   no   |   45 |  700 |  790 | |         |          |          |                  
    7 |Brand C|P2| |  8%  | |   no   |  600 |  150 |   40 | |  Result |    191.5 |          |          
    8 |Brand D|P1| | 12%  | |   yes  |  900 |   90 |  980 | |         |          |          |                    
    9 |Brand D|P1| | 20%  | |   yes  |  125 |  854 |  726 | |         |          |          |          
    10|Brand D|P3| | 19%  | |   yes  |   70 |  860 |  614 | |         |          |          |          
    11|Brand D|P4| |  2%  | |   yes  |  842 |  250 |   85 | |         |          |          |          
    12|Brand E|P4| |  6%  | |   no   |  300 |  324 |  450 | |         |          |          |   
       


I want to calculate the SUMPRODUCT by multiplying the values from Column D with the corresponding values in Column G:I. 
The SUMPRODUCT formula should also consider the filters for the Row in Cell K2 and the Column in Range L2:L4 and Range M2:M4.
In the example above the result is:
L7 = 7%x70 + 12%x90 + 20%x854 + 2%x250 = 191.5


With reference to the answer in this question I tried to apply this solution:
=LET(
    a, IF(
        COUNTA($L$2:$L$3) = 0,
        N(ISNUMBER(ROW($A$2:$A$12))),
        COUNTIF($L$2:$L$3, $A$2:$A$12)
    ),
    b, IF(
        COUNTA($M$2:$M$3) = 0,
        N(ISNUMBER(ROW($B$2:$B$12))),
        COUNTIF($M$2:$M$3, $B$2:$B$12)
    ),
    c, CHOOSECOLS($A$2:$I$12, 3, XMATCH($K$2, $A$1:$I$1)),
    SUM(a * b * CHOOSECOLS(c, 1) * CHOOSECOLS(c, 2))
)

However, it returns 0 as result. As far as I can tell this is caused by the empty Column C. 
I assume somehow in this formula the Column D must be declared as fixed column to be used for the SUMPRODUCT.
Do you have any idea how to change the formula to make it work?

In your existing formula make it 4 in place of 3 that will make it work! or else use XMATCH() as ratio the lookup_value

Hey, the answer I posted for the other question (78533198) would work here. Please give it a try if you wish.

This works on my end, instead of hard coding the column position use XMATCH() to make it dynamic:


• Using BYROW() :
=LET(
     α, A2:I12,
     δ, COUNTIF(L2:L4,TAKE(α,,1)),
     ε, COUNTIF(M2:M4,INDEX(α,,2)),
     φ, IFS(SUM(δ)=0,ε,SUM(ε)=0,δ,1,δ*ε),
     SUM(BYROW(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(α, φ),XMATCH("ratio",A1:I1),XMATCH(K2,A1:I1)),
 LAMBDA(a, PRODUCT(a)))))


• Or without using LAMBDA() helper:
=LET(
     α, A2:I12,
     δ, COUNTIF(L2:L4,TAKE(α,,1)),
     ε, COUNTIF(M2:M4,INDEX(α,,2)),
     φ, IFS(SUM(δ)=0,ε,SUM(ε)=0,δ,1,δ*ε),
     Σ, CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(α, φ),XMATCH("ratio",A1:I1),XMATCH(K2,A1:I1)),
     SUMPRODUCT(TAKE(Σ,,1)*TAKE(Σ,,-1)))


BTW, you can use this custom LAMBDA() formula as well:
=LET(
     λ,LAMBDA(α,δ,ABS(AND(ISBLANK(δ))-MMULT(--(α=TOROW(δ)),{1;1;1}))),
        SUM(FILTER(G2:I12,G1:I1=K2)*D2:D12*λ(A2:A12,L2:L4)*λ(B2:B12,M2:M4)))


However, you can remove the XMATCH() for the ratio column and make it hard-coded with column_index 4 if the column is always fixed.

Per OP's comments:

The formula works. The only time it gives a #CALC is when I remove ALL
column criteria. Is there also way that it will calculate the
SUMPRODUCT if ALL column criteria is empty?


Final Updated Formulas:
=LET(
     α, A2:I12,
     δ, COUNTIF(L2:L4,TAKE(α,,1)),
     ε, COUNTIF(M2:M4,INDEX(α,,2)),
     φ, IFS(SUM(δ)=0,ε,SUM(ε)=0,δ,1,δ*ε),
     Σ, CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(α, IF(SUM(φ)=0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(α))^0,φ)),XMATCH("ratio",A1:I1),XMATCH(K2,A1:I1)),
     SUMPRODUCT(TAKE(Σ,,1)*TAKE(Σ,,-1)))


Or,
=LET(
     α, A2:I12,
     δ, COUNTIF(L2:L4,TAKE(α,,1)),
     ε, COUNTIF(M2:M4,INDEX(α,,2)),
     φ, IFS(SUM(δ)=0,ε,SUM(ε)=0,δ,1,δ*ε),
     SUM(BYROW(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(α, IF(SUM(φ)=0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(α))^0,φ)),XMATCH("ratio",A1:I1),XMATCH(K2,A1:I1)),
     LAMBDA(a, PRODUCT(a)))))



The formula works. The only time it gives a #CALC is when I remove ALL column criteria. Is there also way that it will calculate the SUMPRODUCT if ALL column criteria is empty?

@Michi sorry for the delay, I was not in front of the computer, I have posted a screenshot it is still working even if the ColCrit is blank! please check!

Is it also working on your side when both ColCrit1 and ColCrit2 are entirely blank?

@Michi sorry i missed i will update. give me sometime, I left the computer again.

@Michi updated now!

When I use the updated formula I get the correct value when I empty all ColCrit1 and ColCrit2. However, when I enter these criteria again the value remains the same. It is always 416. Do you have the same issue on your side?

@Michi just make this part φ to SUM(φ) i,e. IF(SUM(φ)=0,1,φ) sorry this will not work

Now it works when I enter criteria for ColCrit1 and ColCrit2 but when they are all empty I am getting #VALUE error.

@Michi see now, But the custom LAMBDA() does work in all scenarios isnt it?

Now it works. Thanks for additional help. I cannot check the LAMBDA function because my Excel does not recognize the BYROW function yet. I assume I need to update to the newest version.

Change:
c, CHOOSECOLS($A$2:$I$12, 3, XMATCH($K$2, $A$1:$I$1)),

To:
c, CHOOSECOLS($A$2:$I$12, 4, XMATCH($K$2, $A$1:$I$1)),

Or:
c, CHOOSECOLS($A$2:$I$12, XMATCH("ratio", $A$1:$I$1), XMATCH($K$2, $A$1:$I$1)),


